# Tracked Ignored and --assume-unchanged how to for Merging

Tags: git

In my Git repo, there is a configuration file that i would like to keep different from the main shared repo(it has to stay tracked) so the changes don't populate to other developers. The '--assume-unchanged' works well to keep my changes locally while pushing code into other repository, however. The problem becomes, when i need to get the up to date code and I am pulling or merging from shared repo into mine local, then i get error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

The error make sense because i have the configuration file different from the one in the shared repo i am merging from. But how do i get pull(merge) newest code while keeping this configuration different.  I would like to avoid the work around:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged app/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
git stash save "config file"
```

and then after merge get my changed configuration back:

```
git stash apply
```

How to avoid these extra steps of stashing and indexing - assume unchanged? Is there way to pull everything but one file? Any other solutions for the problem described?

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you want to ignore a file locally (means that other developers will still track the file) Thus `.gitignore` will not help you since its effects are global.

But, if you add the file to `.git/info/exclude`, it will be locally ignored.

This sentence is from [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do not need to be shared
>        with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary files that live inside the repository
>   but are specific to one user's workflow) should go into the $GIT_DIR/info/exclude file

Comment: Thank you ogzd. I could also do global ignore:git config --global core.excludesfile pathTo/.gitignore_global. However, the ignore does not apply if the file is tracked by git which is the case and it needs to be that way. More in http://margotskapacs.com/2013/02/locally-untracked-files-in-git-while-making-a-grails-plugin-in-place/

Comment: No problem to push code(the configuration file indexed --assume-unchanged), but problem to pull or merge(it appears that --assume-unchanged doesn't apply for merging/pulling). I hope it make sense.